# iText PdfAcroForm: Missing getAllFormFields in version 7.2.5

Tags: java, itext

I am working with iText to manipulate a pdf. So I try to extract the fields in it, as:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader, new PdfWriter(dest));
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
Map<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.getAllFormFields();
```

For my experiment code, I use version 8.0.0-SNAPSHOT, and it has method getAllFormFields in PdfAcroForm, and it returns all the fields in pdf.

But in production, I cant use this version, and I am using version latest in central maven repo:

```
https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/forms/7.2.5/versions
```

But it doesn't have getAllFormFields. Instead it has getFormFields. But this method is returning empty Map for same pdf document.

How can I get all those fields in this version 7.2.5?

Comment: that's pretty odd, getFormFields should just work ([example here](https://github.com/itext/i7js-examples/blob/cad567553884874d95150af88dd352006df577c5/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/acroforms/CheckBoxValues.java)). Can you attach the PDF document?

Comment: (Ps.: 8.0.0 should be released May 10th)

Comment: Beware, there is a major version jump for a reason, there are breaking changes from 7.x to 8.0.0.

Comment: I noticed the same issue while upgrading old code. It appears that in later versions it was added again. I see a `GetFormFields` in 7.2.5 but in 8.x versions I see `GetAllFormFields`. No reference whatsoever in any "breaking changes" log, of course. Couldn't even find a matching PR...